# re-import aliased/shadowed python built-in methods

Tags: python, numpy

If one has run

```
from numpy import *
```

then the built-in `all`, and several other functions, are shadowed by `numpy` functions with the same names.

The most common case where this happens (without people fully realizing it) is when starting `ipython` with `ipython --pylab` (but you shouldn't be doing this, use `--matplotlib`, which doesn't import anything into your name space, but sets up the gui-related magic, instead).

Once this has been done, is there anyway to call the built-in functions?

This is worth doing because the built-in `all` can deal with generators, where as the `numpy` version can not.

Comment: But why use `from numpy import *` in the first place?

Comment: @Akavall Because when you start ipython with `ipython --pylab` it gets pulled in.  For interactive work, it is very convenient.  This is one of the few hang ups.

Comment: For posterity: in recent IPythons you should just use `ipython --matplotlib` instead, which does all the setup but doesn't import anything. (To have easy access the plotting stuff you can then do `import pylab as pl`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can just do

```
all = __builtins__.all
```

The statement `from numpy import *` basically do two separate things

1. imports the module `numpy`
2. copies all the exported names from the module to the current module

by re-assigning the original value from `__builtins__` you can restore the situation for the functions you need.

Comment: Thank you. Suspected I was missing something simple.

Comment: `__builtin__` (singular) will also work.  When you start ipython with `ipython --pylab` `__bulitins__` is a dict, not a module because of `numpy.__builtins__` which shadows `__builtins__`.

Answer (score 2):

You can correct these en masse by re-importing the builtins:

```
In [1]: all
Out[1]: <function all>

In [2]: from numpy import *

In [3]: all
Out[3]: <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.all>

In [4]: from __builtin__ import *

In [5]: all
Out[5]: <function all>
```

Comment: On the other hand, in the context in which one would use `--pylab` the numpy version of things like `sum` and `max` are the ones you want (IMO).

Comment: Tbh I always prefix with np, I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: I tend to agree, but the point of `pylab` is to replicate at MATLAB terminal, for better or worse.

Comment: idk if this answer is Python 2.x specific but on Python 3.8 I had to use `from builtins import *` rather than `from __builtin__ import *`