# What's wrong with Pandas plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I'm following a book by Wes McKinney and in the section introducing pandas, he's given a simple example of plotting a pandas Data Frame. Here're the lines I wrote:

```
tz_counts = frame['tz'].value_counts() # frame is a Data Frame
tz_counts[:10] # works fine till here. I can see the key-value I wanted
tz_counts[:10].plot(kind='barh', rot=0)
```

It just prints a line on screen that says

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x3d14ed0>
```

rather than displaying a plot window as I'd expect with matplotlib's plot function. What's wrong here? How can I make it work?

Comment: How did you start IPython? Did you run `ipython --pylab`? If you just did `ipython` then you'll get what you're reporting.

Comment: even though its irrelevant, I suggest running "ipython qtconsole --pylab inline" if you have qtconsole installed. I personally felt that much more comportable.

Comment: I had no idea "comportable" was a word.

Comment: @PhillipCloud its just a typo, comfortable is what I meant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Matplotlib doesn't show the plot until you tell it to, unless you're in "interactive" mode.

*Short Answer*: Call `plt.show()` when you're ready to display the plot.

This starts the gui mainloop of whatever backend you're using, so it is blocking.  (i.e. execution will stop until you close the window)

If you want it to show up automatically without stopping execution, you can turn on [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html) either with `plt.ion()` or by using `ipython --pylab`.

---

However, using `--pylab` mode in ipython will import all of numpy, matplotlib.pyplot, and a few other things into the global namespace.  This is convenient for interactive use, but teaches very bad habits and overwrites functions in the standard library (e.g. `min`, `max`, etc).

You can still use matplotlib's interactive mode in ipython without using "pylab" mode to avoid the global import. Just call `plt.ion()`

Matplotlib's default `TkAgg` backend will work in interactive mode with any python shell (not just `ipython`).  However, other backends can't avoid blocking further execution without the gui mainloop being run in a separate thread. If you're using a different backend, then you'll need to tell `ipython` this with the `--gui=<backend>` option.

Comment: you just beat me. I was writing the same answer. But probably it should be --pylab

Comment: @PhillipCloud - I just got lucky and saw the question right as it was posted :)

Comment: @rafee - Good catch, thanks. Incidentally, both `-pylab` and `--pylab` work with newer versions of ipython.  `--` is more consistent, though.

Comment: I don't recommend using `pylab` mode for anything; importing numpy's `any` and `all` into scope was a terrible mistake, given that they behave so differently from the builtins.  And fortunately, these days, `-pylab` has been deprecated and using `--matplotlib <backend>` and importing `pylab` manually is encouraged.

Comment: @DSM - Good point, and I completely agree. Namespaces are a very, very good thing. However, that having been said, a lot of people who are just starting with matplotlib/ipython/etc have no idea which backend they're using. Therefore, pylab mode is an easy answer.  I should still update my answer to include the backend portion, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774388/re-import-aliased-shadowed-python-built-in-methods <- how to fix the `any` and `all` clobbering for those interested

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
%matplotlib 
tz_counts = frame['tz'].value_counts()
tz_counts[:10].plot(kind='barh', rot=0)
```

Using % matplotlib prevents importing * from pylab and numpy which in turn prevents variable clobbering.