# PyLab does not have any attrs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with PyBrain and in the documentation it uses PyLab... I try importing PyLab and that works, however when I try using any of the modules in it python returns an error.

```
    >>> import pylab
    >>> dir(pylab)
    ['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__',   '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
    >>>
```

PyLab appears to be installed correctly but it doesn't have any contents.

Comment: Try print(pylab.__file__) and see it is pointing to correct installation on your hard disk. Another potential cause is circular swallowed import error caused by bad coding practices.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why that happen… So let's find out what's happening.

The PyLab you've installed is very likely the one from pypi:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylab

which is actually the one here:

- https://github.com/javipalanca/pylab

and when you look at the files, it's matching what you're saying:

- https://github.com/javipalanca/pylab/blob/master/pylab/pylab.py

it's quite empty ☺

Though, if you install it, it's gonna install you a lot of dependencies for scientific development:

- https://github.com/javipalanca/pylab/blob/master/requirements.txt

Though, since you've installed the `pylab` package, you've got `matplotlib` installed, and thus you can use the pylab which is actually part of matplotlib:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987916/1290438

So if you do from `matplotlib.pylab import *` you should get started!

HTH

Comment: I strongly discourage doing `from matplotlib.pylab import *` specifically and the use of the `pylab` name space in general.  Explicitly use `import numpy as np` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  It helps to keep things organized and prevents issues like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774388/re-import-aliased-shadowed-python-built-in-methods